# Mongodb connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

I set up a mongoDB database with SSL security on an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server and I have been using it for a few months. To set up SSL on mongo I followed the tutorial by Rajan Maharjan on medium.com [(link)](https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/secure-your-mongodb-connections-ssl-tls-92e2addb3c89). Coming back to my server after a short period of not using it, I received the following error message:

`SSL peer certificate validation failed: certificate has expired`

Looking at the mongo log, I found:

`[PeriodicTaskRunner] Server certificate is now invalid. It expired on 2018-11-10T08:10:11.000Z`

So I regenerated and re-signed all my certificates with the rootCA.key file, following the same steps as when creating certificates for the first time. I restarted mongod with:

`service mongod restart`

And now I have the "self signed certificate" error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://IP:port/
2018-11-21T13:11:10.584+0000 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate     
validation failed: self signed certificate
2018-11-21T13:11:10.584+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: 
couldn't connect to server IP:port, connection attempt failed: 
SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

My connection string is the following:

`mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /PATH/TO/rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /PATH/TO/mongodb.pem --host IP:port`

I have not found any resources on re-signing certificates for mongoDB. Any help would be much appreciated.

### EDIT

/etc/mongod.conf :

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: PORT
  bindIp: IP
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/rootCA.pem

# how the process runs
 processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
security:
   authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Are you using the correct sslCAFile?
 Shouldn't it be `/PATH/TO/abc.crt` ?

Comment: @AniketMaithani I tried using the .crt as per your suggestion, I get `Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host` and `SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate` in the log. The connection string in my question is the same I used before and it used to work.

Comment: Adding the `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` option in the mongo connection string yields the following error message: `[js] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host` and `SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate` in the log.

Comment: Hey @Nicolas can you post your /etc/mongod.conf file here ?
Meanwhile try using the following : https://dpaste.de/U4Lm

Comment: Hi @AniketMaithani I edited my question to add the .conf file. I tried your solution (and commented out the rootCA.pem line in the .conf file) but with `mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem` I get `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating` and when restarting the service, in the log I have the following error `WARNING: No SSL certificate validation can be performed since no CA file has been provided`

Comment: Can you remove comment out the `CAFile: /etc/ssl/rootCA.pem` part from your mongod.conf. And restart the service.

Comment: @AniketMaithani I get the same errors as before. the mongod command still returns `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating` even though the .conf file points to another directory (this does not happen with the mongo command)

Comment: You can try using `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work again by following these steps (which, for some reason, did not work before):

- Remove `mongodb.*` files from `/etc/ssl/`
- regenerate certificates with the commands

  ```
  openssl genrsa -out mongodb.key 2048
  openssl req -new -key mongodb.key -out mongodb.csr
  ```
- Server address in the field `Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []`
- Generate the certificate

  ```bash
  openssl x509 -req -in mongodb.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey /PATH/TO/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mongodb.crt -days 500 -sha256

  cat mongodb.key mongodb.crt > mongodb.pem

  chmod 666 mongodb.pem

  service mongod restart

  cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (*to check status*)
  ```

#### And to launch the mongo shell

```
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /PATH/TO/rootCA.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /PATH/TO/mongodb.pem --host IP:PORT
```

Thank you @AniketMaithani for trying to help me solve this issue.

Comment: hello Nicolas Gaborel. where we can find the rootCA.key on local mongodb?

Comment: @GayathriB you can generate your own keys with openssl, this tutorial is quite good: https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/secure-your-mongodb-connections-ssl-tls-92e2addb3c89

Comment: Hiii  Nicolas Gaborel. I have followed this link and I am able to connect to the server. But this process is only for testing purpose, right? and we should provide server.pem to clients in order to connect to the server. Here there is a chance to encrypt the server.pem. so, Is there any alternative ways to connect the MongoDB server using SSL certificates?

Comment: @GayathriB I used this SSL certification internally, not for public web connections. I am not sure what the best practice is in this case, I suppose you should check out some web security tutorials or deal with your DB on the server-side only.

Answer (score 0):

On a related issue for Node js applications, where anyone is receiving the error in DB logs:

> SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections

Check if your connection string has the parameters tls=true and tlsCAFile, if you are using an older version of mongo driver in your node project, you need to use

```
ssl=true and sslCAFile
```

Parameters instead.